# contents of cell overflowing with margin, padding and border

Tags: html, css

I think the main problem is that I'm confused about the padding, border and margin interactions.

I have read about each of these style attributes on their own but I'm having trouble combining all of them successfully inside of a table.

For one, I'm setting attributes on the contents in the cell, and then on the cell themselves. I'm not sure when to do which.

For two, I can use percent or pixels. For my needs I think percent would work well, since the text in the orange box is going to be of variable lengths (as will the header text).

Now, the part of the code that I can't get to work correctly is that the display: inline-block element (including padding, border, and margin) overflows the cell. Obviously I want the first header to be centered over the contents below, and I want each of the orange buttons to be visually centered with a small margin between them and the cells to the right.

I see there's a box-sizing style solution, but I need this to be compatible with IE6.

http://codepen.io/kokeefe/pen/dMmPMp

```
a.TableButtonStyle:link {
    display: inline-block;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color:rgb(240,80,40);
    border-radius: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left: auto; 
    margin-right: auto;
    color: white;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-color: rgb(240,80,40);
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5%;
    font-size:14pt;

}
a.TableButtonStyle:hover {
        background-color: white;
        color: rgb(240,80,40);
}
a.TableButtonStyle:active {
        background-color: rgb(213, 57, 15);
        color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(213, 57, 15);
}
a.TableButtonStyle:visited {
        background-color: rgb(213, 57, 15);
        color: white;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(213, 57, 15);
}

.FontFormat{
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size: 13pt;
    margin: 5px;
}
.Bold
{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: @scriptHero In the title, I need to stop the inline block from overflowing past the width of the cell.

Comment: Then please remove all the section where you are "not sure" what to do, and basically monologuing. State what you've done, your issue, and relevant codez - that's all you need until someone comes along and asks you for _clarification_.

Answer (score 1):

[**Updated CodePen**](http://codepen.io/rahul-desai/pen/XdqYLR)

What you need is:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Apply this to `a.TableButtonStyle`.

Quoting [from MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing):

> **border-box:**
>   The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when the document is in Quirks mode. Note that padding and border will be inside of the box e.g.  .box {width: 350px; border: 10px solid black;} leads to a box rendered in the browser of width: 350px. The content box can't be negative and is floored to 0, making it impossible to use border-box to make the element disappear.

[CSS `box-sizing` property MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this that will be supported in IE7?